# How to add background Image to a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following code that adds a UIToolbar on the top of the keyboard when a textField is tapped.

How can I add a background image to one of the buttons?

I tried...

```
toolBar.items![1].setBackButtonBackgroundImage(clearButton, forState:.Normal, barMetrics:.Default)
```

but it didn't work, I get error...

> Use of unresolved identifier 'imageName'

Code:

```
func addButtonsToKeyboard(){
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    toolBar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(someFunction)),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(someFunction)),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button3", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(someFunction))]

    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    toolBar.items![1].setBackButtonBackgroundImage(myImage, forState:.Normal, barMetrics:.Default)

    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

BTW - The image `myImage` is located in `Assets.xcassets`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to create a UIImage variable, and then pass that in just to be more explicit:

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "myImage")
toolBar.items![1].setBackButtonBackgroundImage(myImage, forState:.Normal, barMetrics:.Default)
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, no error it just doesn't show anything. I changed the height of the UIToolbar, I also tried changing the index to 0, 1 and 2 but nothing. If I do `print(myImage)` I get `Optional(<UIImage: 0x7f96ebfc2ff0>, {103, 103})` , so it looks like it is targeting the image it just doesnt show it. Thanks